# To solve warning 'is never used' in WPF

Tags: wpf, warnings

I have declared an event in "Question" class as:

```
public event SectionAffected OnSectionAffected;
```

I have not used this event in the entire class.But I have used it in another class as:

```
Question.OnSectionAffected += new Question.SectionAffected(ResetDependentSection);
```

I am getting warning as:

The event 'QuestionManager.OnSectionAffected' is never used in Question class.

How to solve this warning?

Comment: from where are you raising this event then?

Comment: I am raising this event in another class.

Comment: how can you raise event from outside the class?

Comment: We can.It is just that my code is running properly but I am getting the warning.

Comment: as far as i know... event can only be subscribed or unsubscribed from outside the class i.e on class instance.. only the class owning the event can raise it.. thats why i asked the above question... also can you share the code how are u raising the event

Comment: I'm also very curious how the event would be raised outside the `Question` class. Please let us share your knowledge.

Comment: In Question class i hv this:
public event SectionAffected OnSectionAffected;

In Screen class I have:
Question.OnSectionAffected += new Question.SectionAffected(ResetDependentSection); and  private void ResetDependentSection(IList<String> dependentSections)
        { //some code}

Comment: That's not raising the event, but just subscribing to it. Raising the event would mean to call `OnSectionAffected(...)` somewhere in class Question, with `...` being the arguments as defined by the SectionAffected delegate.

Comment: And don't suppress a warning (as suggested by the answer) when you haven't even understood its meaning. Try to understand what the compiler is telling you and remove the cause of the warning.

Comment: exactly... you can subscribe to this event 1000 times but you will never get the notification until you raise it from within the Question class..and once you raise this event..this warning will be gone

Comment: ohh thanx @Clemen for correcting my mistake.But how to solve such warnings? But I don't want such warnings after building my projects.

Comment: Either raise the event somewhere in class Question or remove it entirely. It is pointless to have an event that is never raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A warning is just that... a warning. Having warnings is not necessarily a bad thing. However, if you really want to remove it, you can specify that in Visual Studio. If you open the relevant project's property page (by pressing ALT + Enter when the project is focused), turn to the `Build` tab. Click the `RadioButton` named `Specific warnings` and enter the specific error code(s) that you want to supress in a comma separated list. You can find out more from the [How to: Suppress Compiler Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj715718.aspx) page on MSDN.

UPDATE >>>

I believe that you are looking for the numerical error code number... for this, you should look in the `Output` Window of Visual Studio. If you don't already use this window when writing WPF, then I would *strongly* advise you to do so. However, these codes are not *always* shown in this window.

As an alternative, you can find descriptions and error codes in the [C# Compiler Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx) and [Code Analysis for Managed Code Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee1hzekz.aspx) pages on MSDN.

UPDATE 2 >>>

After doing a quick search online (which is really what *you* should have done), I found this page which seems about right: [Compiler Warning (level 3) CS0219](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kycwe2x.aspx)